# How to append null (00 00 ect bytes) to a file until certain size via Python

Tags: python, null, append, hex

I have a file that I need to append NULL or 00 ~ ect bytes to the end of the file (in hex) so the file size would be 625423968.

Right now the file size is: 606256432

I tried:

```
with open(f, 'wb') as binfile:
    binfile.write(b'\x00' - 19167536)
```

but my file size becomes 0

Doing it manually in Hex Editor takes way too long

Greatly appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seek your file and then write the last NULL.

```py
with open(f, 'wb') as binfile:
    binfile.seek(625423968 - 1)
    binfile.write(b'\x00')
```

(Maybe you have to use file-mode `"br+` when you write your file not from scratch in python. This will keep the content and append the NULLs.)

Comment: I must have read too fast or inaccurately, sorry. Solve this now your problem?

Comment: yes, I changed from wb to br+ and reran the script, it did append the nulls to the end of the file. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in (binary) *append* mode and the bytes will be added to the end of the file.

```py
with open(f, 'ab') as f:
    f.write(b'\x00' * 19167536)
```

In-terminal demo:

```sh
$  python -c 'f = open("hello.bin", "wb");f.write(b"hello");f.close()'
$  xxd hello.bin 
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f                             hello
$  python -c 'f = open("hello.bin", "ab");f.write(b"\x00" * 32);f.close()'
$  xxd hello.bin 
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  hello...........
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 00                             .....
```